# Call a function in one Javascript file from another Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, dynamic, external

I need to call a function in an external ".js" file from another ".js" file, without referencing the external file in the `<head>` tag.

I know that it is possible to dynamically add an external ".js" file to the  which allows access to that file, i can do that like so...

```
var AppFile = "test/testApp_1.js"; 
var NewScript=document.createElement('script');
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]; 
NewScript.src = AppFile;
headID.appendChild(NewScript);
```

However...

this is no use to me as the external files need to be stand-alone files that run start-up procedures on...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{...}
```

so adding the full file dynamically has an unwanted affect. Also, i cannot pre-reference the external file in the `<head>` tag as it needs to be dynamic.
So, this external file `"test/testApp_1.js"` contains a function that returns a string variable...

```
function setAppLogo(){

 var LogoFile = "test/TestApp_1_Logo.png";

 return LogoFile;
}
```

I need access to either this function, or I could store the string as a global var in the external file... either way is fine, I just need access to the value in `LogoFile` without loading the whole external file.

This one has had me stumped for a few hours now so any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you dynamically add in the `<head>`? domready won't fire until all JS and CSS and HTML are loaded...

Comment: because by dynamically adding in the head, i end up running code that is unwanted here. I only need one variable value from this file, not the whole file.

Comment: You can't load part of the file... You could load it with XHR and then `eval()` the result... But you shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from having some sort of `app.js` file that contains global variables/values that you will want to use from lots of places.  You should include this `.js` file on every page (and maybe minify it/concatenate it with other js if you want to be clever and improve performance).  Generally these globals should be attached to some object you create such as `var APPNAME = { };`  with variables/functions on it that will be used from many places.

Once you have this, then the external '.js' file that you want to load, and the one you are currently in, can both access the global APPNAME variable and all its attributes/functions and use them as desired.  This may be a better approach for making your javascript more modular and separatable.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load the file once jQuery has loaded using ajax, and then run the related script in the successful ajax function.

See jQuery's getScript function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.getScript("http://domain.com/ajax/test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(data); //data returned
    console.log(textStatus); //success
    console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
    console.log('Load was performed.');
    //run your second script executable code here
 });
});
```

Comment: The OP said "adding the full file dynamically has an unwanted affect", this is exactly the same as adding the script to the header.

Comment: yeah, this code runs the complete file which has undesired effects here, really what i need is to be able to dip into this file and run only the one function I need, something like... `myFile.theFunctionINeed();` or get the value of a variable within the file, i.e. `myFile.globalVar_1`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load the whole script through XHR (e.g. [$.get in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) and then parse it, perhaps using a regular expression, to extract the needed part:

```
$.get('pathtoscript.js', function(scriptBody) {
    var regex = /function\s+setUpLogo\(\)\s*\{[^}]+}/g;
    alert(scriptBody.match(regex)[0]); // supposed to output a function called
                                       // 'setUpLogo' from the script, if the 
                                       // function does not have {} blocks inside
});
```

Nevertheless, it shall be noted that such an approach is highly likely to trigger maintenance obstacles. Regular expressions are not a best tool to parse JavaScript code; the example above, for instance, will not parse functions with nested {} blocks, which may well exist in the code in question.

It might be recommended to find a server-side solution to the problem, e.g. adding necessary script path or its part before the page is sent to browser.

Comment: I like your idea! its a bit mad, but i guess it would work... i could write a function to take in a file, then parse it for the desired function, its mad and probably a bad idea, but that "out of the box" thinking is cool to come accross! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea but you can create an iframe and eval the file inside its 'window' object to avoid most of the undesired side effects (assuming it does not try to access its parent). Then you can access whatever function/variable you want via the iframe's window object.

Example:

```
function loadSomeJsInAFrame(url,cb) {
        jQuery.get(url,function(res) {
            iframe = jQuery('<iframe></iframe>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
            iframe[0].contentWindow.eval(res);
        if(cb) cb(iframe[0].contentWindow);
    },'text');
}

loadSomeJsInAFrame('test/testApp_1.js',function(frameWindow) {
    console.log(frameWindow.setAppLogo());
    jQuery(frameWindow.frameElement).remove();
});
```

This will not guarantee that the sript in the file can not mess with your document, but not likely if it comes from a trusted source.

Also, don't forget to remove your iframe after you get what you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everybody for all the input but i think that what I was trying to do is currently not possible, i.e. accessing a function from another file without loading that file.
I have however found a solution to my problem. I now query my server for a list of apps that are available, i then use this list to dynamically build the apps in a UI. when an app is then selected i can then call that file and the functions within. Its a bit more complex but its dynamic, has good performance and, it works. Thanks again for the brainstorming! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible with the help of [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). You would be able to run your script you've wanted to inject in kinda isolated environment, so it won't mess up your current page.

As you said, it is possible for `setAppLogo` to be global within `"test/testApp_1.js"`, so I will rely on this statement.

In your original script you should create a worker, which references to a worker script file + listen to messages that would come from the worker:

```
var worker = new Worker('worker.js');
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    // ....
};
```

Then, in the worker (`worker.js`), you could use special function `importScripts` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries)) which allows to load external scripts in worker, the worker can also see global variables of these scripts. Also there is a function `postMessage` available in worker to send custom messages back to original script, which in turn is listening to these messages (`worker.onmessage`). Code for `worker.js`:

```
importScripts('test/testApp_1.js');

// "setAppLogo" is now available to worker as it is global in 'test/testApp_1.js'

// use Worker API to send message back to original script
postMessage(setAppLogo());
```

When it invokes you'll get the result of `setAppLogo` in you listener:

```
worker.onmessage = function (e) {
    console.log(e.data); // "test/TestApp_1_Logo.png"
};
```

This example is very basic though, you should read more about Web Workers API and possible pitfalls.